# Add jobs to a customer in QuickBooks DeskTop using QBFC

Tags: quickbooks

I have a C# application and I want to add jobs to a customer using QBFC 12.0.

To explain further, say I have an object `Customer` with a nested object `Jobs` (here jobs are 5 lets say), first the customer syncs on QuickBooks Desktop and then its corresponding Jobs.

Comment: Reena, you must Always provide the code you have so far.

Comment: Is this even a programming question, or a software support question?

Answer (score 1):

To add a job to a customer using QBFC you need to use a CustomerAdd object of QBFC. For entering job you need to add the listID of parent or ParentFullName of the job. QBFC will take care of generating the sublevel for the job you need to enter.

```
ICustomerAdd CustQ = default(ICustomerAdd);
CustQ = requestSet.AppendCustomerAddRq();
CustQ.Name.SetValue(jobName);
CustQ.ParentRef.FullName.SetValue(parentFullName);
IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestSet);
```

Comment: How will you add custom fields through this interface?